# How do I view my old wordpress site, after having redirected to Squarespace

Tags: wordpress, hosting, squarespace

I recently pointed my 1&1 registered domain, masonsmn.com, away from justhost where I had a wordpress site built toward my new site constructed using squarespace.

I would like to view a few pages of the old site as they were previously (i.e. I messed up. In hindsight a few screenshots then would have been a good idea).

Does anyone know how I can access those wordpress pages at this point?

Thanks,

Comment: archive.internet.org - aka the way back machine

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hosts entry to your computer to force it to go to the old IP address. See [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+hosts+file) for instructions for your operating system. Don't forget to remove it later! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The old site is on justhost. Do you still use them for hosting? If so, just download your old wordpress files via ftp. If you already cancelled your hosting, but it wasn't long ago, they may have your files backed up still. If this is the case I would give them a call and see what they can do.